# How to aggregate with NA values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Is there a way to aggregate with NA values?

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5),
                  id = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15), 
                  k = c(8, 5, 3, 1, 7), 
                  score = c(0, 9, 22, 3, 4))
df1

##   A id k score
## 1  1 11 8     0
## 2  2 12 5     9
## 3 NA 13 3    22
## 4  4 14 1     3
## 5  5 15 7     4
```

And I want to group column **score** by columns **A** and **k**, one of which has NA value.

So when I run

```
aggregate(x = df1[, "score"], by = df1[, c("k","A")], 
          FUN = sum, na.action=na.pass)
```

I get the following result

```
##    k A x
## 1  1 8 1 0
## 2  2 5 2 9
## 3  3 1 4 3
## 4  4 7 5 4
```

But I want to get the same thing as using sqldf

```
sqldf::sqldf("SELECT A, k,
                     SUM(score) 
             FROM df1
             GROUP BY A, k")

##    A k SUM(score)
## 1 NA 3         22
## 2  1 8          0
## 3  2 5          9
## 4  4 1          3
## 5  5 7          4
```

So how can I have this result using only base R functions?

Thanks.

Comment: first are you grouping with `k` also? How can you select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) paste/type.convert** Convert A to character using `paste`. That will also convert NA to the character string "NA".  Then at the end convert back.

```
transform(aggregate(score ~ k + A, transform(df1, A = paste(A)), sum),
  A = type.convert(A))
##   k  A score
## 1 8  1     0
## 2 5  2     9
## 3 1  4     3
## 4 7  5     4
## 5 3 NA    22
```

or the same thing expressed as a pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)

df1 %>%
  transform(A = paste(A)) %>%
  aggregate(score ~ k + A, ., sum) %>%
  transform(A = type.convert(A))
```

**2) replace with -Inf** A variation of the above is to replace NA with -Inf and then convert back at the end:

```
transform(aggregate(score ~ k + A, transform(df1, A = replace(A, is.na(A), -Inf)), sum),
  A = replace(A, is.infinite(A), NA))
##   k  A score
## 1 3 NA    22
## 2 8  1     0
## 3 5  2     9
## 4 1  4     3
## 5 7  5     4
```

**3) collap** `collap` in the collapse package will preserve the NA's:

```
library(collapse)

collap(df1, ~ k + A, fsum)[-2]
##    A k score
## 1  4 1     3
## 2 NA 3    22
## 3  2 5     9
## 4  5 7     4
## 5  1 8     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `NA` with the string `"NA"`.

```
df1[is.na(df1)]<-"NA"
aggregate(x = df1[, "score"], by = df1[, c("A","k")], 
          FUN = sum)

   A k  x
1  4 1  3
2 NA 3 22
3  2 5  9
4  5 7  4
5  1 8  0
```